# How to add a delay to a function in a single line for a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have an issue, I need to delay a function in a bookmarklet, but im unsure how, since most delaying functions require more than one line of code

```
javascript:var result = confirm("Attempt to perform function"); if(result) while (true) { alert("function performed!")() } else { alert("Cancelled function."); }
```

I would like to add a delay between the confirmation of trying to perform a function, and when it actually performs the functions (maybe 3 seconds?)
any suggestions? thanks.

(my friend recommended requestAnimationframe, but i am unsure how to implement this as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to execute a function after some delay, you should use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

For example, this will execute after three seconds (3000ms):

```
setTimeout(() => alert("function performed!"), 3000);
```

---

Also, if you're building bookmarklets, there are helpful tools out there [like this one](http://subsimple.com/bookmarklets/jsbuilder.htm) or [this one](https://caiorss.github.io/bookmarklet-maker/) that will let you write "normal" Javascript and then transform it into a single line for you. Might make your life a little easier.

Comment: when running as 
`javascript:var result = confirm("Attempt to perform function?"); if(result) while (true) { setTimeout(() => alert("function performed!"), 3000); } else { alert("Cancelled function."); }`

it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You don't need `while (true)`. The `setTimeout` call should be the entire body of your `if` statement:

`javascript:var result=confirm("Attempt to perform function?");if(result){setTimeout(()=>alert("function performed!"),3000);}else{alert("Cancelled function.");}`